# Bootstrap 4 - scrollSpy not updating nav links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement Bootstrap 4 `scrollSpy` feature on my site. I have given the body position relative:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

And I have made nav-links underneath the navbar:

```
<div class="container-fluid page-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3">
          <nav id="page-nav" class="nav section-links">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#info">Info</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#videos">Videos</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#stats">Statistics</a>
         </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am making the nav links fixed once I scroll to them:

```
  $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#page-nav' });

  let pageNav = document.querySelector('.page-nav');
  let fixClass = 'is-fixed';

  function stickyScroll() {
    if( window.pageYOffset > 56 ) {
      pageNav.classList.add(fixClass);
    }
    if( window.pageYOffset < 56 ) {
      pageNav.classList.remove(fixClass);
    }
  }
  $(window).scroll(stickyScroll);
```

I add the is-fixed class to make them fixed:

```
.is-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
}
```

But, scrollSpy is not working, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: your query selector is a class not id.

Comment: That is for making the nav links container fixed, and that is working fine, and for scrollSpy I am using id as a selector for nav links, and even when I change the target to the class page-nav, it is still not working

Comment: Then change it to var fix = $(".is-fixed") and fixClass would be simply fix.  Because it is a registered class not a comment

Comment: That has nothing to do with bootstrap scrollSpy not working